Websocket error while connecting signalR using Angular and ASP.NET Core
I am using Angular and ASP.NET core for sending notification using SignalR and I am getting these errors:

Although connection is established and notification is also send and received. I don't understand these errors and don't know how to resolve them.
This is my SignalR service in Angular:
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import { AuthService } from "../../core/auth/services/auth.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:48348/notificationHub", {
        headers: {
          "x-api-key": environment.apiKey,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveNotification", (message: string) => {
      console.log("Notification received:", message);
      // You can update the UI or perform any action here
    });

    this.startConnection();
  }

  private startConnection() {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log("Connection started"))
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error while starting connection: " + err));
  }
}

this is my program.cs file
 using ELM.Application;
using ELM.Infrastructure.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Serilog;
using System.Text;
using EML.WebApi.Middlewares;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using ELM.Application.Hub;
using ELM.Application.Hub.Service;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Load configuration from appsettings.json
var appsettingsconfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") // Optionally, if you have a JSON configuration file
            .Build();


// Configure Serilog from appsettings.json
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(appsettingsconfiguration)
            .MinimumLevel.Error() // Set the global minimum logging level to Error
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();

builder.Host.UseSerilog();


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingConfig));
builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.RegisterRepositoryServices();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
   {
       builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
   });
});

var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
{
    cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"])
        ),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description =
            "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n " +
            "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\n" +
            "Example: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

    // Define x-api-key authorization scheme
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("apiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Please enter your API key",
        Name = "x-api-key",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    // Require API key for all endpoints
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "apiKey"
                }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
});

// Configure database context
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ELMDB"))
);
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
var app = builder.Build();


app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// Configure CORS
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");


// Add custom middleware for API key validation
app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();

// Enable HTTPS redirection
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseWebSockets();
app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");

// Map controllers
app.MapControllers();

// Run the application
app.Run();

I am using api-key and jwt token for authorization and authentication.
In angular when i consoled x-api-key and token then it is correct but it is still throwing unthorized and others errors

could you try this code : this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()   .withUrl("https://localhost:48348/notificationHub", {     headers: {       "x-api-key": environment.apiKey,       Authorization: Bearer ${token},     },     transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | signalR.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents | signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling   })   .build();

401 error, you are getting because authorization token might be incorrect, expired, or not being handled properly by the server. Make sure bearer token provided in the Authorization header is valid and properly fetched from the AuthService. Double-check token .is it possible for yu to share the reproducible sample with us . The above code have suggest you to force SignalR to use only WebSocket by setting the transport type

Apart from that you could add middleware code which can help you log the incoming request which will also include what headers are being sent. use some tool like fiddler to capture the request

Try the below code in your signalR service, to resolve this error.
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import { AuthService } from "../../core/auth/services/auth.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:48348/notificationHub", {
        accessTokenFactory: () => token,
        headers: {
          "x-api-key": environment.apiKey,
        },
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | signalR.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents | signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling,
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect() // Enables automatic reconnection
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information) // Optional: adds logging
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveNotification", (message: string) => {
      console.log("Notification received:", message);
      // You can update the UI or perform any action here
    });

    this.startConnection();
  }

  private startConnection() {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log("Connection started"))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error while starting connection: " + err);
        setTimeout(() => this.startConnection(), 5000); // Retry connection after 5 seconds
      });

    this.hubConnection.onclose((error) => {
      console.error("Connection closed due to error:", error);
      setTimeout(() => this.startConnection(), 5000); // Retry connection after 5 seconds
    });
  }
}


Answers really should include an explanation and not just code. It makes them much more helpful to people in the future who encounter the same issue and find this on Google.

i tried this code but its given same errors as  before any onthe suggestions??
